# How to install tar.gz files?

Tags: software-installation

I want to install Mumble and the file name is *mumble-1.2.8.tar.gz*. Can you help me from here?

I'm on Ubuntu 13.10 (Saucy Salamander) using KDE on a Chromebook (installed with Crouton).

Comment: I think Ubuntu should have binary packages for this. Check this first. Do `apt-cache search mumble` on the command line.

Answer (score 1):

Linux/Unix is VERY unlike Windows. (this is a good thing)  A number of the concepts from Windows completely and utterly do not apply.

I can only speak in the broad sense, but with a package like that, you want to decompress it to a set of directories that it has included in the archive formatting.  Then you may want to move those directories to some other location within your directory tree.  For things that aren't executable, this is generally a trivial move (like moving something to a webhost directory).  For things that are executable programs, there is generally something that indicates how to move the generated binaries to the right locations within the path so that they are usable by all users.

I don't know, or care to inform myself on which case this is.

Answer (score 1):

If you open the `tar.gz` file with the archive manager, or file-roller and look at the INSTALL instructions it shows the procedure by pointing to:  http://wiki.mumble.info/wiki/BuildingLinux

How to use a terminal in ubuntu: https://askubuntu.com/questions/38162/what-is-a-terminal-and-how-do-i-open-and-use-it

This is all directly from the install instructions.

Install the dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential pkg-config qt4-dev-tools libqt4-dev libspeex1 \
                libspeex-dev libboost-dev libasound2-dev libssl-dev g++ \
                libspeechd-dev libzeroc-ice-dev ice-slice libpulse-dev slice2cpp \
                libcap-dev libspeexdsp-dev libprotobuf-dev protobuf-compiler \
                libogg-dev libavahi-compat-libdnssd-dev libsndfile1-dev \
                libg15daemon-client-dev libxi-dev
```

And extract the gzip tar file (tarball) and change to that directory:

```
tar xzfv mumble-x.x.x.tar.gz       # (whereas the X are the version numbers of mumble)
cd mumble-x.x.x
```

And then compile:

```
qmake -recursive main.pro
make
```

Answer (score 0):

one solution is :

```
$tar -zxvf program.tar.gz     
$tar -zjvf program.tar.bz2
```

Change the directory to unzipped folder, i.e.:

```
cd /download/program/     

./configure     

make
```

And then get into the root i.e.:

```
sudo su 

(for suse su is enough)
```

Enter your password.

```
make install
```

and another solution is given [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-do-i-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file)!